# Detect infinite loop inside a method

Tags: java, reflection, infinite-loop

I have 2 methods in my main class

```
public class pol{

    public sub() {
         //... do this
         //... do this
         //... do this
         return result
    }

     public sub2()
         // calling method sub() here
         return result
     }

}
```

Is there any way so that i can detect that i wrote an infinite loop in sub() using method sub2() ?

We can take a scenario where i am loading a class using reflection in sub() and executing it over there ..

Comment: why do you need to detect if you wrote an infinite loop, you wrote both methods?

Comment: suppose if i am using reflection, an infinite loop can cause compiler to not responding state

Comment: Your code does not display any infinite loop.

Comment: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11645/can-a-runtime-environment-detect-an-infinite-loop

Comment: what if second method have infinite loop, is there any way so that i can at lease throw a timeout exception

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Timeout exception mean you waited for certain time, so you need to use timers.

Comment: A dirty way is decompiling it to source code. Then parse it and try to find infinite loop.

Comment: The real question that everything seems to ignore is: WHY you need this, what exactly you are doing that you must detect that infinity loop?

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are running on a single thread, no. Operation will never return to sub2() if there is an infinite loop in sub().

If sub2() spins off a thread that starts a loop in sub() it might still not be possible. That might actually be a Halting Problem thing. Sub2() could interact with the thread sub() is in and kill it after a given time, given number of iterations, or some other criterion. If there is some state you know to check for that would cause an infinite loop sub2() could look for that state and kill sub() if it enters it but Thread has no .isInInfiniteLoop() method.

Comment: i was trying with the thread, but using the same method how can i killl the thread

Comment: Correct. I say "kill" colloquially. You don't actually halt a Thread, rather you put them in a condition to end. For example your loop in sub() might read

    while(booleanContinueFlag) {doStuff();}

In sub2() you would set that flag to false. This will allow it to finish up the iteration it is on and execute any cleanup actions outside of the loop. The thread will then terminate.

Answer (score 0):

As @John M said as long as they are both running in the same thread the operation will never return back to `sub()2` in case there is an infinite loop in `sub()`. However, you could detect it in `sub()2` before entering the loop. This would be possible by assigning `boolean` values to every combination of the loop guard and see if it ever evaluates to `false`. Or you could create a `truth table` for every variable involved in the loop guard and see if the loop guard as a whole ever evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 0):

If there is a certain time by which you expect `sub()` to finish it's job unless it entered an infinite loop, you can use a `Timer` or some code within `sub()` that compares current time to starting time, and stop `sub()` if too much time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

May it will help.

Just put conditions in the all loops you that put in sub().

Let me give you Example:

```
int i=0;
public void Sub(){
  //loop1
  while(true){
    ...
    ...
    if(i>1000){
    i=0;
    throw new Excepion();
    }
  }
  //loop2;
  //loop3; 
}
```

here you can add limit as per your need **1000** is just for example.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to detect an infinite loop is to put a println statement (it can be anything) into your method.  If the loop is infinite, then the println statement will repeatedly print.

If you make method sub2() print this statement, then you can use sub2() to detect the infinite loop in sub().

Comment: Bye seeing i can , but programmatically how ?

Comment: How do you know it will not stop *eventually*?

Comment: Let's say you set a boolean to true, then make a while loop that runs while that boolean is true.  That loop will now run infinitely.  Put in a simple println statement, and it'll appear infinitely.

Answer (score -1):

For debugging purposes, you can implement a counter and increment for each time the function is called. If the counter reaches a certain threshold, you can exit, call another function, print something to console, etc.